# Android GCM push notifications - sending notification to a specific device instead of all devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I followed Google GCM [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html). But It runs notification to all the devices instead of specific device.How can I send notification to particular device.

I believe registration ID is needed for me. But definition of registration id is :

```
An ID issued by the GCM servers to the Android application that allows it to receive 
messages. Once the Android application has the registration ID, it sends it to the 
3rd-party application server, which uses it to identify each device that has registered 
to receive messages for a given Android application. In other words, a registration ID 
is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device.
```

Here what is the meaning of 3rd party Application.

Please guide me on this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Replace "3rd-party application server" for the word "server-side" on the definition you have copied. Registration ID is a combo of device ID+application, it is unique and ideal to use it on your server side in order to indetify who are you interacting with from your server. Look at this [image to undersand it](http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/gcm-a-modr.png).

Answer (score 2):

> But It runs notification to all the devices instead of specific device

Since GCM does not support sending a notification to all devices, this is not possible. GCM supports sending a message to a specific device, or to all devices registered to same user (if you use [the opt-in user notifications feature](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html)).

> Here what is the meaning of 3rd party Application.

This is defined on [the very Web page that you linked to](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html). You can tell this by reading that page, and seeing:

> 3rd-party Application Server: An application server that you write as part of implementing GCM. The 3rd-party application server sends data to an Android application on the device via the GCM connection server.